# Trouble with C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: c++

I am just beginning to study object-oriented programming, and I'm getting lost.  My code is getting bizarre errors I don't understand or know how to fix.  I have 3 files for this program.  First file:
House.h

```
#ifndef HOUSE_H_
#define HOUSE_H_


class House {
public:
    void buildHouse();
    void destroyHouse();
};



#endif
```

Second file, Classes.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "House.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    House house;

    house.buildHouse();
    house.destroyHouse();

    return 0;
}
```

Third file, House.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "House.h"

using namespace std;

void House::buildHouse() {
    cout << "Build that house!" << endl;
}

void House::destroyHouse() {

    cout << "Destroy that house!" << endl;
}
```

I am getting four errors:

1. _main already defined in Classes.obj
2. unresolved external symbol "public void_thiscall House::buildHouse(void)" (?buildHouse@House@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function_main
3. unresolved external symbol "public void_thiscall House::destroyHouse(void)" (?destroyHouse@House@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function_main
4. 2 unresolved externals

Comment: Did you add `House.cpp` to your project?

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. You do need to `#include "stdafx.h` in `House.cpp` though.

Comment: Don't use build/destroy member functions, use constructor/destructor instead.

Comment: What project template did you use (I'd recommend an empty project)? Also, I'd recommend to not use stdafx.h.

Comment: The first one is strange. Do you have another `main` in a file you're not showing? Look for errors in the Output tab instead of the Error List for more context.

Comment: I used a console application.